# Delphi TDockZone resizing with rsUpdate style

Tags: delphi, docking

I use TPanels for docking in my project, where I can dock more forms into.
But the docking zones resize only with "rsPattern" style.
I want them to resize in the "rsUpdate" style.

Because Controls.TDockTree unfortunately has all necessary routines private (not allowing to change this in any TDockTree descendant - because TDockZone.FOrientation is only private etc.), I made custom copy of Controls.pas for my project and modified that code directly.

That way is sufficient for me because it works as expected but with each Delphi upgrade I have to change this code again, for new Controls.pas (when it would change).

Is there some cleaner way (of course without using external libraries)? Or how do you solve such problems?

Comment: You can use class helper to access private fields..

Comment: Just prefix it with "Self" in the method implementation in you class helper.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based on useful hint of ZENsan and extends CaptionedDockTree.pas (tested in Delphi XE):

```
type
  TDockZoneHelper = class helper for TDockZone
  private
    function GetOrientation: TDockOrientation;
    function GetParentZone: TDockZone;
  public
    property ParentZone: TDockZone read GetParentZone;
    property Orientation: TDockOrientation read GetOrientation;
  end;

  TDockTreeHelper = class helper for TDockTree
  private
    function GetBorderWidth: Integer;
  protected
    procedure HlpForEachAt(Zone: TDockZone; Proc: TForEachZoneProc);
    function HlpInternalHitTest(const MousePos: TPoint; out HTFlag: Integer): TDockZone;
    procedure HlpSetNewBounds(Zone: TDockZone);
    procedure HlpUpdateZone(Zone: TDockZone);
  public
    property BorderWidth: Integer read GetBorderWidth;
  end;

{ TDockZoneHelper }

function TDockZoneHelper.GetOrientation: TDockOrientation;
begin
  Result := Self.FOrientation;
end;

function TDockZoneHelper.GetParentZone: TDockZone;
begin
  Result := Self.FParentZone;
end;

{ TDockTreeHelper }

procedure TDockTreeHelper.HlpForEachAt(Zone: TDockZone; Proc: TForEachZoneProc);
begin
  Self.ForEachAt(Zone, Proc);
end;

function TDockTreeHelper.GetBorderWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := Self.FBorderWidth;
end;

function TDockTreeHelper.HlpInternalHitTest(const MousePos: TPoint;
  out HTFlag: Integer): TDockZone;
begin
  Result := Self.InternalHitTest(MousePos, HTFlag);
end;

procedure TDockTreeHelper.HlpSetNewBounds(Zone: TDockZone);
begin
  Self.SetNewBounds(Zone);
end;

procedure TDockTreeHelper.HlpUpdateZone(Zone: TDockZone);
begin
  Self.UpdateZone(Zone);
end;


{ TMyCaptionedDockTree additions }

procedure TMyCaptionedDockTree.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Zone: TDockZone;
  Flag: Integer;
begin
  FSizingZone := nil;
  if (Button = mbLeft) and not (ssDouble in Shift) then
  begin
    FSizingPoint := Point(X, Y);
    Zone := HlpInternalHitTest(FSizingPoint, Flag);
    if Flag = HTBORDER then
      FSizingZone := Zone;
    else
      inherited;
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TMyCaptionedDockTree.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if FSizingZone <> nil then
  begin
    FSizingPoint := Point(X, Y);
    if FSizingZone.ParentZone.Orientation = doHorizontal then
      FSizingZone.ZoneLimit := FSizingPoint.y + (BorderWidth div 2)
    else
      FSizingZone.ZoneLimit := FSizingPoint.x + (BorderWidth div 2);
    HlpSetNewBounds(FSizingZone.ParentZone);
    HlpForEachAt(FSizingZone.ParentZone, HlpUpdateZone);
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TMyCaptionedDockTree.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  FSizingZone := nil;
end;
```